# How can I install WildFly 8.0.0.Final as service on Ubuntu Linux?

Tags: java, ubuntu-12.04, wildfly8

I am trying to install the [WildFly 8.0.0.Final](http://www.wildfly.org/) application server on a Virtual Machine running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I've done some searches on Google, but I found only [third-party scripts](https://gist.github.com/sukharevd/6087988) and, I think, non standard ways to do this.

Currently, to start the server, I open an SSH connection to the virtual machine and run the following commands:

```
cd <WILDFLY_HOME>/bin
nohup standalone.sh -b=0.0.0.0 -bmanagement=0.0.0.0 > /dev/null &
```

And to stop:

```
kill <pid of java process running wildfly>
```

But, **what is the best way** to install the server **as a service** on Ubuntu? If I restart the machine, the server will start automatically?

My environment:

- Ubuntu 12.04 LTS;
- Java 7;
- WildFly 8.0.0 Final;

Comment: You could use a wrapper like [`tanukiwrapper`](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/) or [`supervisord`](http://supervisord.org/).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

WildFly includes an init.d script in the bin folder...

Follow this steps:

```
sudo cp $WILDFLY_HOME/bin/init.d/wildfly-init-debian.sh /etc/init.d/wildfly
sudo cp $WILDFLY_HOME/bin/init.d/wildfly.conf /etc/default/wildfly
sudo adduser --system --group --disabled-login wildfly
sudo chown -R wildfly:wildfly $WILDFLY_HOME
sudo update-rc.d wildfly defaults
```

Modify /etc/default/wildfly to fit your needs...
Test.

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion the best way is to use installation script:

> wildfly-8.0.0.Final/bin/init.d/wildfly-init-debian.sh

it will create you init script so if you want WildFly to start automaticly you should execute command:

> update-rc.d wildfly defaults

after execution of wildfly-init-debian.sh script

Answer (score 2):

[EDIT]

<del>The accepted answer is outdated, the scripts have been moved to:</del>

The accepted answer is actually technically correct, since the question is about WildFly 8. Thanks @JorSol for pointing that out!

However, I got here while searching for "installing WildFly 10 as a service on Ubuntu", and I am sure others will too.

In **WildFly 10**, the location of the `init.d` file has been moved to:

> `$WILDFLY_HOME/docs/contrib/scripts/inid.d`

Comment: The question is to the version 8.0.0 of WildFly, so the accepted answer is technically correct.

Comment: @JorSol you are right, I have updated my answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would modify the previous answer from JorSol to

```
sudo cp $WILDFLY_HOME/bin/init.d/wildfly-init-debian.sh /etc/init.d/wildfly
```

because his command would create a security exploit should anyone be able to gain the permissions of `wildfly` and modify `$WILDFLY_HOME/bin/init.d/wildfly-init-debian.sh`.