# Cannot start Wildfly

Tags: debian, debian-wheezy, init.d, wildfly8

I want to start wildfly as a service but nothing happens when I try to start it using:

```
$ /etc/init.d/wildfly start
Starting WildFly Application Server: wildfly
$ ls -l /etc/init.d/wildfly 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 6786 Feb 10 16:06 /etc/init.d/wildfly
```

Then, when I type `ps -ef`, there is no wildfly or java process.

I followed this post: [How can I install WildFly 8.0.0.Final as service on Ubuntu Linux?](https://serverfault.com/questions/583723/how-can-i-install-wildfly-8-0-0-final-as-service-on-ubuntu-linux)

It works using this command: `/opt/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh`
Permission on wildfly folder are:

```
$ ls -l /opt
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 11 sonar   adm     4096 Feb 11 08:38 sonar
lrwxrwxrwx  1 wildfly wildfly   25 Feb 10 16:06 wildfly -> /opt/wildfly-8.2.0.Final/
drwxr-xr-x 10 wildfly wildfly 4096 Nov 21 05:43 wildfly-8.2.0.Final
```

I have the following java version:

```
# java -version
java version "1.8.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_31-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.31-b07, mixed mode)
```

**Why init.d wildfly service does not work?**

Comment: ```# service wildfly start```

Comment: Nothing changes, wildfly does not start :/

Comment: check wildfly logs

Comment: try running the init script (it is bash script) in debug mode: 'bash -x /etc/init.d/wildfly start'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem and the solution. It is because `pidofproc` command is missing.

Line 151:

```
check_status() {
    pidofproc -p "$JBOSS_PIDFILE" "$JAVA" >/dev/null 2>&1
}
```

I fixed it at line 158 by replacing:

```
check_status
status_start=$?
if [ $status_start -eq 3 ]; then
#...
fi
```

By:

```
check_status
status_start=$?
if [ $status_start -ge 3 ]; then
#...
fi
```